# What's the safest, most portable way to invoke the echo binary?

Tags: linux, echo, coreutils, portability

The `echo` in `coreutils` seems to be ubiquitous, but not every system will have it in the same place (usually `/bin/echo`). What's the safest way to invoke this `echo` without knowing where it is?

I'm comfortable with the command failing if the coreutils `echo` binary doesn't exist on the system -- that's better than echo'ing something different than I want.

Note: The motivation here is to find the `echo` binary, *not* to find a set of arguments where every shell's `echo` *builtin* is consistent. There doesn't seem to be a way to safely print just a hyphen via the echo builtin, for example, without knowing if you're in `zsh` or `bash`.

Comment: `$(find / -perm +001 -type f -exec sh -c 'strings "$1" | grep -q "GNU coreutils" && strings "$1" | grep -q "Echo the STRING(s) to standard output." && echo "$1"' sh {} \; | head -n 1)`?

Comment: (Use `printf`).

Comment: [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard: echo doesn't have a portable way to avoid appending a newline  at the end of the line. `printf()` is simply a wrapper around the C `printf` function, which is part of the C standard library; you pretty much can't get any more portable than that.

Comment: @BartonChittenden, I know.  I was providing a link, not asking a question.

Comment: `env echo ...` will find and invoke it (unless there is a serious problem, e.g. with PATH)

Comment: Let's assume you can't use `printf` (you can, unless you're running on systems which won't have a single `coreutils` binary on them, like Unix v7 or the stripped down and ridiculously locked down Android builds). You are _still_ better off figuring out how to portably test-and-use whatever-echo-you-got: it's much more likely to succeed than finding a specific `echo` implementation.

Comment: does `\echo work` (that is a back slash), for all shells?

Comment: @richard Nope. `busybox` `sh`/`ash` will invoke its own builtin `echo` instead of an external `echo` binary when given `\echo`.

Comment: @richard Unless you were just asking if `\echo` worked syntactically to invoke something/anything named `echo`, in which case, it should be syntactically valid in all Bourne-likes. Just no guarantees about what exactly it'll invoke (alias, function, builtin, or external binary) that I would rely on.

Comment: @VPfB What when `env` isn't in `$PATH`?

Comment: @cat IMHO `env` not in `$PATH` is an error condition that would be noticed very quickly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `coreutils` is a software bundle developed by the GNU project to provide a set of Unix basic utilities to GNU systems. You'll only find *coreutils `echo`* out of the box on GNU systems (`Debian`, `trisquel`, `Cygwin`, `Fedora`, `CentOS`...). On other systems, you'll find a different (generally with different behaviour as `echo` is one of the least portable applications) implementation. FreeBSD will have FreeBSD `echo`, most Linux-based systems will have busybox `echo`, AIX will have AIX `echo`...

Some systems will even have more than one (like `/bin/echo` and `/usr/ucb/echo` on Solaris (the latter one being part of package that is now optional in later versions of Solaris like the for GNU utilities package from which you'd get a `/usr/gnu/bin/echo`) all with different CLIs).

GNU `coreutils` has been ported to most Unix-like (and even non-Unix-like such as MS Windows) systems, so you would be able to compile `coreutils`' `echo` on most systems, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Also note that you'll find incompatibilities between versions of `coreutils` `echo` (for instance it used not to recognise `\x41` sequences with `-e`) and that its behaviour can be affected by the environment (`POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable).

Now, to run the `echo` from the file system (found by a look-up of `$PATH`), like for every other builtin, the typical way is with `env`:

```
env echo this is not the builtin echo
```

In `zsh` (when not emulating other shells), you can also do:

```
command echo ...
```

without having to execute an extra `env` command.

But I hope the text above makes it clear that it's  not going to help with regards to portability. [For portability and reliability, use `printf` instead](/q/65803).

Comment: Thanks, great explanation with caveats. Didn't think of `env` but it's exactly what I want, although I will generally use `printf` over `echo`.

Answer (score 7):

```
# $(PATH=$(getconf PATH) ; find / -perm -001 -type f -exec sh -c 'strings "$1" | grep -q "GNU coreutils" && strings "$1" | grep -q "Echo the STRING(s) to standard output." && printf "%s" "$1"' sh {} \; | head -n 1) --help
Usage: /bin/echo [SHORT-OPTION]... [STRING]...
  or:  /bin/echo LONG-OPTION
...
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) echo invocation'
```

I think this is a bad idea, to be honest, but this will do a pretty solid job of finding the coreutils `echo` in a reasonable environment. Those are POSIX-compatible commands all the way through ([`getconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html), [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html), [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), [`strings`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strings.html), [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), [`head`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html)), so it should behave the same everywhere. The `getconf` gives us the POSIX-compliant versions of each of those tools first in the path, in cases where the default versions are non-standard.

It finds any executable that contains both printable strings "GNU coreutils" and "Echo the STRING(s) to standard output", which appear in the GNU `echo`'s `--help` output and are literally in the program text. If there's more than one copy, it arbitrarily picks the first one it found. If there's none found, it fails - the `$(...)` expands to an empty string.

---

I wouldn't call it "safe", however, since the presence of this (executable) script anywhere on the system would cause you some troubles:

```
#!/bin/sh
# GNU coreutils Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.
rm -rf /
```

So to reiterate, I think this is a very bad idea. Unless you're going to whitelist hashes of known `echo`s, there's no reasonable, portable way to find a given version of it that is *safe* to run on unknown systems. At some point you're going to have to run something based on a guess.

---

I would encourage you to [use the `printf` command instead](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), which accepts a format and any arguments you want to use literally.

```
# printf '%s' -e
-e
```

`printf` is in POSIX and should behave the same way for all systems if you provide a format.

Comment: If you want to be _sure_ that you're portable against arbitrarily perversely non-standard/limited commands (Solaris 10 is my favorite finger-pointing target in this matter, but there are other offenders, thankfully all at least as obscure as the former) you might want to also replace `grep -q` with `grep .>/dev/null`. If you need to run under `busybox-w32`, there's also the matter of `NUL` instead of `/dev/null` at that point... Or you do some hacks to read-and-throw-out the output by piping, requiring yet more hacks to not lose the `grep` exit status. Shell script portability is _hell_. :)

Comment: Oh, and `strings` is really not certain to be installed, as it's omitted by default on many more minimal systems in my experience. Still, +1 because if you want to actually be sure you've found the `echo` from `coreutils`, the task of scanning your entire file system tree for `echo` instances, and then scanning those for the right help/etc text is really the only really reliable way if you find yourself on systems where `echo` behavior is a concern.

Comment: @mtraceur Solaris has POSIX-compatible `grep` (and `sh`) in `/usr/xpg4/bin`; that's what the `getconf` is for.

Comment: `strings` is also required by POSIX, so a system that doesn't have it isn't compliant. It's just not possible to write portably for systems that have arbitrary bits missing (maybe `grep`'s not there!).

Comment: Good point about the `getconf`. As for `strings`/POSIX, it all depends on just _how_ portable you need to be. There are possibly more non-compliant systems than compliant ones out there. No `strings` is well in the realm of real-world usage. It's certainly often possible to write portably for a set of systems where some have well-known deviations from standard, if they are capable of doing what you need: it just might be pages of code instead of lines. I'm not saying your example needs to handle that case, but since OP didn't give clear portability requirements, I mentioned it.

Comment: Also, I just noticed a typo in my first comment `.>/dev/null` was supposed to just be `>/dev/null`, but I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: If it's not POSIX-compliant it's not Unix, and therefore off-topic. (Yes, I know; and yes, I know).

Comment: Is that a really useful way to determine what constitutes on-topic though? I realize I have disproportionate concern for writing scripts that need to handle boundary conditions (phones, routers, systems like Mac OS X 10 which for years had an atomicity bug in `rename(2)`, etc), but aren't those still Linux/Unix? I have more Linux systems in my house which somehow deviate from the POSIX spec than I have Unix-like systems which are fully POSIX compliant, and I am not including embedded devices I never have reason to write scripts for.

Comment: Of course it isn't useful (they're not really off-topic). There's no use trying to write general answers covering arbitrary deviations either, though. If you're using something specific the question needs to say.

Comment: Fair enough. Like I said early on, I though your answer was very good even without mentioning those details, and I didn't think you needed to spend the time writing up the code to handle that case. I just wanted to bring it up in a comment in case someone was hoping to target a very broad range of systems, without realizing this was something to think about.

Comment: There **is** no code to handle that case, since you've ruled out relying on literally anything at that point.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear with my point: while there are _many_ devices in the real world that deviate from _specific_ aspects of the spec, there are very few devices in the real world that deviate from other aspects of the spec. I'm not sure why me saying that many systems don't have `strings` in practice is being treated as being equivalent to saying that you can't assume the presence of some Bourne-like `sh`, or `cat`, or `grep`, etc, by definition. I've never seen a Unix-like not have `rm`, but I've seen many which don't have `strings`. Isn't portability a gradient, rather than a boolean?

Comment: I mean, look, I get it - at the deep end, portability is an unsolvable problem: there's always going to be some system somewhere which can't support something or other. We all eventually have to draw the line for what the lowest common denominator among the systems we care about is. I'm not saying you're wrong for drawing the line at the POSIX spec - that's very reasonable for most purposes - I just draw it in a different location, to catch a larger subset of systems I have encountered, and I just wanted to alert readers about the delta between our two lines, in case it was relevant to them.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, so I'm out. One *might* want to contemplate the phrase "[portable against arbitrarily perversely non-standard/limited commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356686#comment632218_356689)", however.

Comment: Thank you (genuinely) for reminding me of my original wording. Looking back, it was too absurdly absolute/general, and presumably set the stage for interpreting everything I said after that completely wrong. You were absolutely right that I ought to contemplate that phrase. It just served as a vivid reminder for me of a notable flaw in how I sometimes articulate things really poorly when leading into topics like this under some circumstances. Since further elaboration is definitely off-topic, I'll just close on a sincerely thank you: I think you've helped me grow as a mind.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I avoid `echo` completely in my shell scripts and use `printf '%s\n' blablabla` when the string is short and here-document when the string is long.

Quoting from [§11.14 Limitations of Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#Limitations-of-Builtins) of the [autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/):

> **echo**
>
> The simple `echo` is probably the most surprising source of portability troubles. It is not possible to use `echo` portably unless both options and escape sequences are omitted. Don't expect any option.
>
> Do not use backslashes in the arguments, as there is no consensus on their handling. For `echo '\n' | wc -l`, the `sh` of *Solaris* outputs `2`, but *Bash* and *Zsh* (in `sh` emulation mode) output `1`. The problem is truly `echo`: all the shells understand `'\n'` as the string composed of a backslash and an `n`. Within a command substitution, `echo 'string\c'` will mess up the internal state of *ksh88* on *AIX 6.1* so that it will print the first character `s` only, followed by a newline, and then entirely drop the output of the next echo in a command substitution.
>
> Because of these problems, do not pass a string containing arbitrary characters to `echo`. For example, `echo "$foo"` is safe only if you know that *foo*'s value cannot contain backslashes and cannot start with `-`.
>
> If this may not be true, `printf` is in general safer and easier to use than `echo` and `echo -n`. Thus, scripts where portability is not a major concern should use `printf '%s\n'` whenever `echo` could fail, and similarly use `printf %s` instead of `echo -n`. For portable shell scripts, instead, it is suggested to use a here-document like this:

```
          cat <<EOF
          $foo
          EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I'm fairly confident that there is no problem which isn't better solved by doing something other than explicitly invoking an external binary (especially looking for a specific implementation of an external binary).

So as much I normally hate answers that boil down to "you should never need to do this thing you want to do", I'm making an exception here. I will instead suggest numerous alternatives, in order of how strongly I suggest them. If you absolutely must find the right `echo` binary, Michael Homer has the most appropriate answer, and you should read Stéphane Chazelas' answer too because it brings up several locations in a file-system that you might not expect to find `echo` binaries. I also have some additional caveats about searching for the "right" echo in my last section of this answer.

## `printf`

I have never seen a system which was intended to actually run custom shell scripts and which saw real use in the last couple of decades which didn't ship with a `printf`. I have certainly never seen a system which came even close to including something as large as GNU `coreutils` which didn't ship with a `printf` out of the box.

For perspective, I am obsessed to the point it's unhealthy with shell script portability, and I have access to literally only *two* systems with a Bourne-like shell right now which don't have `printf`: A virtualized Unix v7 (yes, the one from four decades ago or so), and one (out of about five in my possession) Android device which basically has *nothing* installed and is so locked down it's not going to be running any useful shell scripts any time soon anyway.

This will print your string *exactly*, on - I promise - every system that deserves to be used by anyone in modern times:

```
printf '%s' "$my_var_holding_my_text"
```

and

```
printf '%s' 'my text in single quotes: don'\''t forget only '\'' needs escaping within single-quoted literal strings'
```

UNLESS you also need to print out *null* bytes. I doubt you need to. If you do, you can't have the entire text as *one* argument to printf *anyway*, since most shells (`zsh` deserves praise here) use null bytes as string terminators. So you'd use `\000` octal escapes within your format string (the first argument) and combine that with zero or more `%s` and zero or more further arguments to print all the other text. Hex escapes (vs octal) and other tricks are less portable, as far as I know.

Suggestion: Don't put *anything* you don't *need* specially parsed/converted into the format string. Different `printf` implementations support slightly different formatting (including modern `printf` implementations, e.g. `bash` builtin vs `busybox printf`).

If you want the extra newline appended to your output, an extra `\n` is trivial to add to your format string:

```
printf '%s\n' foo
```

is a strictly unambiguous/works-the-same-everywhere equivalent of

```
echo foo
```

If you get some convoluted situation where it's not easy to both construct the format string you need (remember you can build the format string programmatically using variables too), you can always include the newline literal into the arguments you're passing to `printf`, or output newline characters by themselves with a bare `echo` with no arguments separately.

## Here-files, or: `cat <<DELIMITER`

```
cat <<DELIMITER
$my_variable_containing_my_text
DELIMITER
```

or

```
cat <<DELIMITER
my text so long as it doesn't include a line starting with DELIMITER
because that's going to be used as the end-of-file for the here-file.
$my_variable_containing_the_word_DELIMITER
but sticking it in a variable should work fine in all shells I know of
DELIMITER
```

The one caveat is that you can't control if you get a newline at the end or not: You always *will* get a newline at the end. Most of the time, this is probably what you wanted or it doesn't matter. Also, many (all?) shells use temporary files on disk to implement here-files, so it's possible to run into a situation where a very restricted system doesn't allow this (the same obscenely crippled Android instance without `printf` I have also has SELinux policies, or some other permissions limitation (I don't remember precisely) which prevent the shell from creating temporary files).

Because of this, on a computer-security note, if you need to print sensitive information, a here-file could either be worse or better than an `echo`, depending on the exact system (is `echo` external or a builtin? is /proc/$PID world or user readable? are here-files user or world readable?), and your exact threat-model (is your threat more likely to forensically search your disk than your running process information?)

## `expr`

A little-known feature of `expr` is that it can extract and print substrings from within an argument with a regex match. This is basically a more portable version of the original `echo` behavior (print contents verbatim, and one newline character), and is an even more portable way to print plain text than `printf`:

```
expr X"$my_var_holding_my_text" : 'X\(.*\)'
```

and

```
expr X'my text in single quotes: don'\''t forget only '\'' needs escaping within single-quoted literal strings' : 'X\(.*\)'
```

This works back to Unix v7. The `X` at the front of both the string/variable to print *and* at the front of the regex *outside* of the `\( \)` sub-pattern match/selection is important: the former keeps the value you're printing from getting mis-interpreted by the `expr` command as an `expr` keyword, and the latter then makes sure the X isn't actually printed.

## `awk`

Here's a compact `awk` one-liner which will print most single-string arguments it receives unambiguously (you'll still have a problem with backslashes on more recent version of `awk` - thanks for Stephan for reminding me of this in the comments):

```
: | awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } END { print v }' v="$my_var_with_my_string"
```

This works back to Unix v7. If you don't have backslashes, this is extremely portable, and might be good enough for the text you need to output. You might also find writing feature-tests for different `awk` implementations in your scripts easier/simpler/cleaner than making `echo` work for you, since while there are definitely many deviations amongst `awk`s, there's less variations to test for than `echo` if your core goal is just writing some exact output.

Obviously use the single-quoted string technique if you want to use a literal instead of a variable. Do an `echo` without arguments if you want a newline after it (or take the time to rigorously vet a specific way to ensure a newline gets printed by the `awk` command - I suggest replacing the `:` no-op command on the left of the pipe with `echo` without arguments, but I haven't carefully audited that idea for across-the-board portability)..

## `echo` piped through `sed` or similar

If you know that your inputs are not special (no backslashed octal escapes like `\000` in the input you want to print literally, and you need to just avoid specially parsing a `-` character, for example, you want to print `-e`, you can still make arbitrary `echo` work for you if you have something else you can use to preprocess `echo`'s output:

```
echo X-e | sed '1 s/^X//'
```

For limited, well-defined inputs, you might be able to get away with trivial `sed` replacements like this. Depending on exactly what you need, it might get progressively harder. At a certain point, it's better to move onto the next alternative:

## Feature-test `echo`

The idea that you cannot reliably make `echo` print exactly what you want, if you're willing to go through pains to do it, is not necessarily true, especially if you have a well-known set of outputs you need. And trust me, it's going to be less painful than searching for just the right `echo` binary somewhere in the file system.

You particularly expressed a concern about reliably printing a `-` character. Unfortunately, I haven't yet written a thorough `echo`-feature-testing shell script snippet, but here's some basic snippets off-the-top-of-my-head:

```
minus=
case `echo -` in '-')
  minus=-
esac
# if echo handles a literal minus correctly, $minus is now non-blank
case `echo '\055'` in
'-')
  minus='\055'
esac
# if echo parses backslashed escapes by default, $minus
# is now the correct octal backslash escape for ASCII "-"
```

You can construct similar tests for specific things: `echo -e '\055'` (shoul either output `-e \055` or `-`), `echo -E '\055'` (if it is parsing backslash escapes by default and you want to try turning them off), etc.

Many modern instances of echo will parse other backslash escapes than octal numbers, but you can either feature-test specifically for those (`echo '\x2d'` or whatever) - but I think in most cases, you really just want to find the set of arguments that you can pass to echo to make it print things without doing special substitutions on the contents, then feed it the output you want verbatim.

Depending on your needs, `echo -n` might also be worth testing for, but bear in mind that *command substitution* always strips off the last newline (just the last one on most shells, but all trailing newlines on some shells), so your two likely output options are the literal `-n` and the empty string.

You may also want to consult `autoconf` and `m4` sources, because I think those tools go out of their way to find an echo they can use to do unambiguous printing if they can't find a `printf` or something else that works.

## Literally anything else

I genuinely think just about anything which doesn't depend on you having to brute-force-search for exactly the right `echo` will be best. It's extremely likely that particular `echo` won't be installed, or won't be installed where you look, or that an automatic bruteforce search starting from `/` will bring some poor chap's system down to a crawl.

And while very unlikely, it's possible a binary will pass your finger-printing for being GNU `coreutils` `echo`, but will have a behavioral difference: even if GNU never changes their implementation, someone might wrap their own installed version of GNU's `echo` to not do what they consider to be a dumb behavior (transparently passing through all arguments except for silently dropping the ones that are special while setting the ones they want is trivial in a shell script, so you could easily have `echo --help` print the right text but `echo -e '\055'` does the wrong thing). And no, not even a *binary* that passes thorough fingerprinting is certain: I have edited raw ELF binaries to change behavior before, and I will do it again. Sometimes it's to enable very useful functionality (not silently dropping messages containing non-ASCII bytes, like Unicode smileys, in closed-source messaging software) and sometimes for really petty things, like changing the hardcoded default `PS1` in shells to be `\$\` instead of `\w \$`). I personally don't have enough of a reason to do it to `echo` because on systems I actually use, I just ignore `echo` for almost all serious work, but someone else might feel as strongly about default `echo` behavior as I feel about default `PS1` variable values. So you're back to feature-testing `echo`, at which point see the above section.

Also, please note that I have systems where GNU coreutils `echo` is installed as `gecho`, so neither an efficient search of the `PATH` and likely install locations, nor a bruteforce search for only files named `echo`, will catch those systems.

And I'd actually bet that more systems have some scripting language like `perl` installed, which can do what you want, than systems which have GNU `coreutils` `echo` specifically: some scripting languages are ubiquitous and mostly have one implementation or a well-defined spec, while `echo` implementations are myriad and follow precisely one spec: "do something slightly different than as many other `echo` implementations as possible".

Comment: With `awk`, you need to use `ENVIRON` (or `ARGV`), not with the V7 awk. with `awk -v v="$v" ...` or `awk ... v="$v"`, you'll have problems with backslashes.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you for pointing that out. I clearly need to spend more time remembering the nuances of the different `awk`s.

Comment: `sed` is a neat idea (though hopefully I won't need to do anything that really requires it). In the future I'll definitely keep your idea in mind that "there is no problem which isn't better solved by doing something other than explicitly invoking... a specific implementation of an external binary".